Watching stuff that I'm not supposed to and liking it
I was exposed to two men kissing and since then I want to keep rewatching it because I somehow liked it, I dont go any further, but I'm still worried that this is something that I shouldn't do. Also is reading books haram that includes two men falling in love..
